# Permission denied when trying to execute a binary burned to a CD-R

Tags: linux, permissions, compact-disc, burning

On an Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala) machine, I burned a CD from the command prompt using:

```
cdrecord -v speed=16 dev=0,1,0 /FPS.iso
```

The CD now contains an executable and some files. I tested the CD by loading it onto another machine (Red Hat 5.3) and when I try to run the program I get the following message:

```
bash: ./FPS1_1: Permission denied
```

I can open other files like text documents (the executable also comes with shared libraries).  I realized I had burned the CD as root so I burned another one as another user but I still have the same problem. How can I remove this permission or what is the problem?

P.S. the image was in `/` if that helps.

The command I used to generate the image is:

```
mkisofs -frvJL -o /buffer/mycd.iso /temp/mydirectory/
```

The `-r` stands for "Generate rationalized Rock Ridge directory information".  Should I use `-R` ("Generate Rock Ridge directory information")?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not how you burned the disc but in how you created the image. If you do not enable [Rock Ridge extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Ridge) when generating the ISO then it will use whatever options are specified during the mount operation instead of the permissions it originally had.

Comment: i did enable them actually, well I added r not R

Answer (score 1):

As [Ignacio's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/123348/permission-denied-when-trying-to-execute-a-binary-burned-to-a-cd-r/123349#123349) indicates, this has more to do with generating the ISO and mounting the filesystem than with burning the ISO to disc.

---

You can mount the CDR or ISO with the *umask* option to make sure files have the executable bit in the mounted filesystem.  For example, *umask=022* would give all files permissions of *755*, also known as *rwxr-xr-x*.

```
mount -t iso9660 -o umask=022 /dev/cdrom /path/to/mount/point
```

This will fix the permissions issue once; for a permanent fix, add the *umask* option to your system mounting systems (*/etc/fstab*, or any automounters in use), or fix the ISO image.

---

On Ubuntu, *mkisofs* is a symlink to *genisoimage*.  According to the [genisoimage manpage](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/genisoimage/), the *-R* may be closer to what you want than *-r* (emphasis mine):

> -R    Generate SUSP and RR records using the Rock Ridge protocol to further describe the files on the ISO9660 filesystem.
>
> -r    This is like the -R option, but file ownership and
>   modes are set to more useful values. The uid and gid are set to zero,
>   because they are usually only useful on the author's system, and not
>   useful to the client. All the file read bits are set true, so that
>   files and directories are globally readable on the client. **If any
>   execute bit is set for a file, set all of the execute bits**, so that
>   executables are globally executable on the client. If any search bit
>   is set for a directory, set all of the search bits, so that directories
>   are globally searchable on the client. All write bits are cleared,
>   because the filesystem will be mounted read-only in any case. If any
>   of the special mode bits are set, clear them, because file locks are
>   not useful on a read-only filesystem, and set-id bits are not desirable
>   for uid 0 or gid 0.

Comment: thx for the precision, I am going to try it later on